# Why does Xcode install all of the Swift libraries (multiple times) to my device when using Podfile?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I just added a Podfile to my iOS project, and no matter what I set for ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES (even $(inherited)), it still adds all of these swift libraries to my builds. My app was around 20 MB before I added the Podfile and now it's 1.35 GB... I have done a fair amount of Googling and I can't seem to figure out what is causing this. I'm using Xcode 10.1 and here's my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Core Dependencies
  pod 'SwiftLint', '~> 0.29.1'
  pod 'R.swift', '~> 5.0.0.rc.1'
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.4.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.4.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.0'
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift', '~> 12.0.1'

  # Database management
  pod 'RxRealm', :git => 'https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm', :tag => '0.7.7'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.12.0'

  # Remote Image management
  # pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.6.3'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 7.3.1'
    pod 'SnapshotTesting', '~> 1.0'
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 7.3.1'
    pod 'SnapshotTesting', '~> 1.0'
  end

end
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try using Carthage it might reduce size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many hours of frustration, I finally discovered what was causing the problem. It turns out that I was missing an important step: **Clean Build Folder**.

Whenever you make a change to the Podfile, you need to rerun `pod install` and then click 'Clean Build Folder' under the 'Project' menu.

Here is the correct code for the bottom of the Podfile that stops multiple copies of the Swift Standard Libraries from being installed:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = '$(inherited)'
    end
  end
end
```

Once I had done this, my app was back to its original, small size. Happy coding!